# How to select from MYSQL database WHERE its only from two DATETIME?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a tabel in MYSQL database that has 2 columns.

```
1- start_date
2- end_date
```

the above columns both hold DATETIME like so:

```
start_date                  end_date

2019-10-03 13:30:00     2020-10-03 23:30:00
```

I need to select from the MYSQL table ONLY if the `current date` is between the `start_date` and `end_date`.

So i tried this MYSQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `end_date` >= CURDATE() AND `start_date` <= CURDATE()
```

but this doesn't work and doesn't return anything from the database even thogh the the current date is between the start_date and end_date.

Could someone please advice on this?

Comment: No date can be greater than today `>= CURDATE()` and less than today `<= CURDATE()` at the same time.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, when it comes to dates, my head starts making strange noises! don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** I need to select from the MYSQL table ONLY if the current date is between the start_date and end_date.

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE CURDATE() between start_date and end_date
```

Convert it with date before because you're using their timestamp.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE CURDATE() between date(start_date) and date(end_date)
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE NOW() between start_date and end_date
```

Comment: Jeeez. that easy?

Comment: Yep, it's just that easy.

Comment: But that doesn't return anything either! the date i have are `start_date 2019-10-03 13:30:00` AND  `end_date 2020-10-03 23:30:00`. I would expect that to be returned since the currect date is between those two dates!

Comment: Try make `date(end_date)` and `date(start_date)`.

Comment: Note that the second query cannot use an index :-( (but the third option can) :-)

Comment: `cannot use an index` Index like?

Comment: Like INDEX(start_date)

Comment: @Strawberry Let me know if any changes in my answer. I'll do it. if and restriction of mysql.

Comment: @strawberry index won't help in this case... OP wants to compare datetime with a date. You could use date-intersection query to check if the dates intersect with `2020-10-03 00:00 ... 2020-10-04 00:00` but index will not be very useful, if used at all.

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL date function in query

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE date(end_date) >= CURDATE() AND date(start_date) <= CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE start_date >= '2019-10-03 13:30:00' 
AND end_date <= '2020-10-03 23:30:00'
```

Comment: the dates are stored in the MYSQL. cant hardcode them in my php query.